# POD FILE INSTALL OPTIONS

Tags: terminal, cocoapods, podfile

[Terminal NEW TRY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhJw5.jpg)

cocoapods was already installed on computer, but I figured I'd try again.

attached is the newest image of my terminal, still showing same problem.

I'm running iOS High Sierra \ Version 10.13.5.

So sometimes when I install podfile it works, the others times I get this:

```
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

and I'm just confused. I dont understand, what commmand can I run for it to just install the pods that I want?  Cocoapods is already installed, and I'm going through the process correctly.

- `cd Desktop`
- `LS`
- `cd` (folder with developments)
- `cd` Folder with master file
- `cd Master-File-iOS11`
- `pod init` (creates pod file
- `open -a Xcode podfile`
- edit the code and type in the pods I want
- save it
- go back to terminal
- type in `install podfile` and then I get that whole options.. ????

Comment: What are you trying to do? How can you install podfile without cocoapods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create pod file

> - pod init

after creating and editing podfile,  type:

> - pod install

**UPDATE**

This is  the podfile. I have added only two pods just for a short example. You can add whatever you want

```
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘11.0’
use_frameworks!

target ‘your project namne’ do
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'Kingfisher'
end
```

Comment: Yes, I am doing that action, you can see in the most recent photo upload; my pod file reads:    [platform : ios, '9.0' ]      [target 'Clima'][ do ]      [ use_frameworks! ]    ['SwiftyJSON'] ['AlamoFire']     [end]

Comment: do not use **install podfile**, instead run command **pod install**

Comment: Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.

[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
Alexanders-MacBook-Air:Clima-iOS11-master alex_katona$. - thats before and after trying to run 'sudo gem install cocoapods' again, tho I know I've already installed it on my computer?   should I Just try to uninstall and re-install Xcode?

Comment: you don't need to uninstall anything. Just update your podfile and then run **pod install** again. see my updated answer